# How to get an option (each possible selection) from a drop down menu to embed an image <html>

Tags: html, image, drop-down-menu, embed

I don't know what to put instead of the hrefs, seeing as they cannot embed an image. If you could help out here, then that would be great. You may know that I posted a similar question recently, but it wasn't very clear and the answer was not helpful, but thanks anyway.
This is the code:

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left; 15px;
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align:center;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Select Skin</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Mumbo</a>
    <a href="#">Grian</a>
    <a href="#">Iskall</a> 
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from you is to embed an image when you click on option of the drop down list

The way I suggest is to have an attribute of type `data-src` for the option and then use jquery to get that value and append it to a `div` on click

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dropdown-content a").click(function(){
     $(".embeded-images").append("<img src='" + $(this).data("img") + "' />");
  });
});
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left; 15px;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align:center;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Select Skin</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#" data-img="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/glass-transparent-christmas-ball-with-snow_118124-1557.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg">Mumbo</a>
    <a href="#" data-img="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/coffee-topped-with-whipped-cream-coffee-seeds_140725-1121.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg">Grian</a>
    <a href="#" data-img="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/fireworks-new-year-2020-background_52683-29350.jpg?size=664&ext=jpg">Iskall</a> 
  </div>
</div>

<div class="embeded-images"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I am relatively new to html and this is just what I wanted.

Comment: I have just tried to apply this, and it hasn't seemed to work, could you say how I should do this, just so I know what to do. otherwise, this is perfect.

Comment: @BenLloyd it depends on what you are trying to do. This is just an idea on how to go about your problem. However if you need more explanation on the answer, I can edit it for you.